# Using variables in a command results in ! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }

Tags: macros, urls

I want to define a command, which separates a string an later adds a different `\href` to the first part, than to the second (e.g. `\qname{foaf:Person}`). But the code as I have it doesn't work, I get `! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.`, when I try to run it.

```
\RequirePackage{xstring}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{url}    

\newcommand{\prefix}{}%
\newcommand{\postfix}{}%
\newcommand{\qname}[1]{%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{:}{%
        \renewcommand{\prefix}{\StrBefore{#1}{:}}%
        \renewcommand{\postfix}{\StrBehind{#1}{:}}%
        \nolinkurl{\prefix}:\nolinkurl{\postfix}
    }{%
        \url{#1}%
    }%
}
```

If I just output `\prefix` instead of `\nolinkurl{\prefix}:\nolinkurl{\postfix}` it works, but I want to have it as url.

I think there is something wrong with the variable handling, but I couldn't find information about this.

Comment: The resulting package is here: https://gist.github.com/white-gecko/5595112

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please always post a complete document not just a fragment.

If you add

```
\show\prefix
```

you will see it is not exactly the characters before `:` it is

```
> \prefix=\long macro:
->\StrBefore {a:b}{:}.
```

Which presumably does not expand to something hyperref likes.

This version just uses an expandable macro to split on `:`

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{xstring}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{url}    

\newcommand{\prefix}{}%
\newcommand{\postfix}{}%
\newcommand{\qname}[1]{%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{:}{%
        \renewcommand{\prefix}{\StrBefore{#1}{:}}%
        \renewcommand{\postfix}{\StrBehind{#1}{:}}%
\show\prefix
        \nolinkurl{\prefix}:\nolinkurl{\postfix}
    }{%
        \url{#1}%
    }%
}

\def\qname#1{\xqname#1:\valign:\\}

\def\xqname#1:#2:#3\\{%
  \nolinkurl{#1}%
\ifx\valign#2%
\else
:\nolinkurl{#2}%
\fi}

\begin{document}

\qname{aaa}

\qname{a:b}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I don't really understand, what it is doing. Does the `\def` part just replace my definition? (BTW: the else-case `\url{#1}` is not needed)

Comment: @white_gecko It splits on `:` by making a delimited argument so `#1` is everythig up to teh first `:` you can not define such arguments with `\newcommand`. I left in your definition but with `\show` added, if you comment out my later definition you will see the `\show` output that I showed above

Comment: ok, and what is the `\valign` and the `#3` for? I only use #1 and #2 as I think. I have now simplified the `\xqname` to \def\xqname#1:#2:#3\\{
 \href{http://#1}{\nolinkurl{#1:}}
 \href{http://#1#2}{\nolinkurl{#2}}
}

Comment: Your simplified version only works if there is a `:` the `\valign` is just an arbitrary token unlikely to be in the input so if that is the token after `:` there was no `:` originally and the second `\nolinkur;` is not used

Comment: That is fine the argument has to contain a `:`. I've removed the `\valign` and `#3` now. Am I right, that the `\\` is some arbidrary char as end of the command?

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear why you want to split at the colon; however, this is a different way to cope with the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_gecko_prefix_tl
\tl_new:N \l_gecko_postfix_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\qname}{m}
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { \: } { #1 }
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_gecko_prefix_tl { #1 }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_gecko_postfix_tl { #1 }
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { \A (.*) \: (.*) \Z } { \1 } \l_gecko_prefix_tl
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { \A (.*) \: (.*) \Z } { \2 } \l_gecko_postfix_tl
    \nolinkurl{ \l_gecko_prefix_tl } : \nolinkurl{ \l_gecko_postfix_tl }
   }
   {\url{#1}}
 }\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\qname{foo:bar}

\qname{http://tex.stackexchange.com}

\qname{127.0.0.1}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this addresses your issue.  It uses the `stringstrings` package to parse the string.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{url}    

\newcommand{\prefix}{}%
\newcommand{\postfix}{}%
\newcounter{index}
\newcommand{\qname}[1]{%
  \whereischar[q]{#1}{:}%
  \setcounter{index}{\theresult}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{index} = 0}%
    {\url{#1}}%
    {%
      \addtocounter{index}{-1}%
      \substring[q]{#1}{1}{\value{index}}%
      \edef\prefix{\thestring}%
      \addtocounter{index}{2}%
      \substring[q]{#1}{\value{index}}{$}%
      \edef\postfix{\thestring}%
      \nolinkurl{\prefix}:\nolinkurl{\postfix}
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\qname{aaa}

\qname{a:b}

\qname{http://tex.stackexchange.com}

\end{document}
```

[image]