# "Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }" error when using non-English language in \title

Tags: xetex, memoir

*(Other answers ([A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114635/14103), [B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136326/14103)) with similar error message do not actually take care of the situation.)*

I have memoir document which should contain title both in Bangla and English. But when compiled (using xelatex), I get an error message,

> ! Argument of \reserved@a has an
>   extra }.

Here is the MWE which causes the error.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}

\title{\begin{bengali} বইয়ের টাইটেল\end{bengali}
  Book Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

If the part `\begin{bengali} বইয়ের টাইটেল\end{bengali}` is taken out of the file,
the error disappears. So, that line must the culprit here.

As is advised in the questions (or answers) mentioned at the top, I need to protect something. However, I am a little confused what to *protect* here. I even tried putting `\protect` around `\begin{bengali} বইয়ের টাইটেল\end{bengali}`, without any avail. (Just a hunch, not an educated one.)

Comment: You need to protect commands, so you could try \protect\begin .... and \protect\end... (but using an already robust command as suggested in the answer is easier).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\begin`  macro which starts an environment is "fragile", which means it cannot be used inside a moving argument. The `\title` command expands its argument, and therefore fragile commands can't be used inside it.

See the following question for an explanation of this.

- [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/2693)

So the solution is to  not use the `{bengali}` environment inside the title.

(You could actually "protect" the environment by using `\protect\begin{bengali} .... \protect\end{bengali}`) but there is a simpler solution:

Just use `\textbengali{}`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[]{Bangla MN}
\title{\textbengali{বইয়ের টাইটেল}
  Book Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: If you could enrich answer a bit by letting us know why the `\bengali` environment can not be used  inside the title, it would be more enlightening.

Comment: This answer actually helped me with another issue, not related to language environments but returning the same error and stemming from the same basic cause. Turned out I needed to similarly `\protect` my use of `\includegraphics` within `\lettrine`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a complement.  After upgrade texlive 2017 to 2019, I had an equivalent problem.

And i solved problem by add \protect my use of \includegraphics within \lettrine

```
\documentclass{book}
% test-remarque_01
\usepackage{graphics}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\newtcolorbox{myremarque}{
enhanced,
boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
borderline west={4pt}{0pt}{red},
colback=white,
sharp corners
}

\newcommand{\remarquestart}{\lettrine[findent=2pt]{\protect\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{remarque.png}}{ }\textbf{Remarque:}\quad}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{myremarque}
  \remarquestart
  \lipsum[4]
\end{myremarque}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```